# IE detect Javascript Version

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, web-applications

Our site is performing poorly on some client machines, we are deployed mostly on IE 7 and IE 8.  On another set of clients, and in our environment, the site is fast.  I am at a  loss as to what to look for next.

SO , I guess my questions surround:

1. could it be related to a javascript version?
2. IE DOM / rendering version ?
3. Antivirus tampering with files being downloaded by IE?

any other thoughts?

---

Our clients are varirous firms in the financial services market.  I assume they all have ample bandwidth comming into their office, but I should definitely check, more importantly bandwidth available on their networks.

The site is not a public site, it is a web application, unfortunately I don't think I can share without NDA (business folks).

The site is based on ext/js with large amounts of javascript.

---

Added some data from task manager

```
IE NOT RUNNING

Physcial Memory - total: 3036
Physcial Memory - cached: 994
Physcial Memory - available: 1000
Physcial Memory - free: 53

Kernel Memory - Paged: 275
Kernel Memory - NonPaged: 63

System - Handles: 30290
System - Threads: 1012
System - Processes: 69
System - Commit: 3416/6072


IE RUNNIGN GOOGLE.COM

Physcial Memory - total: 3036
Physcial Memory - cached: 980
Physcial Memory - available: 952
Physcial Memory - free: 18

Kernel Memory - Paged: 275
Kernel Memory - NonPaged: 63


System - Handles: 31703
System - Threads: 1057
System - Processes: 72
System - Commit: 3490/6072


IE RUNNING OUR SITE

Physcial Memory - total: 3036
Physcial Memory - cached:933
Physcial Memory - available: 892
Physcial Memory - free: 4

Kernel Memory - Paged: 275
Kernel Memory - NonPaged: 63

System - Handles: 32190
System - Threads: 1057
System - Processes: 74
System - Commit: 3555/6072

LEAVING OUR SITE (to stack), this jumps back up:

Physcial Memory - free: 25
```

Comment: Without the site in question, what shall we do? Start guessing around, like you?

Comment: ie 7/8 have tragic js interpreters, if you have a lot of javascript it may be the case

Answer (score 1):

If it's actually the javascript that is performing poorly, I'd look at the CPU usage/load on the different machines, older, or busier hardware will have a pretty significant effect with complex javascript apps.

Comment: are you talking about cpu and memore of the IE process?  Thats an interesting angle.  Perhaps even the CPU and memory before the application is launched...

Comment: added some taskman stats... The physical memory looks like it gets abused by our site.  I am not sure what that means to my app yet

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the new task manager data, I note the following -- while use does go up with addition of your site *most* of resource use is prior to using the app.  I'd look at performance without outlook, or other apps running in the background.  You might have to require more memory for your application given all else being equal.

---

You give almost no information, but you don't mention connection speed -- so I'm taking a wild guess that some of the users are using a slower connection.  Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the three questions posed:

1. could it be related to a javascript version? **Yes, but probably not**
2. IE DOM / rendering version ? **Yes, but probably not**
3. Antivirus tampering with files being downloaded by IE? **Yes**.

Any Other thoughts? 
Find the commonality between the places where it is slow that doesn't exist in places where it is fast. For example, are all the slow users exclusively:
a) Sharing the same internet connection?
b) Using the same version of the browser?
c) Using the same/similar anti-virus software?
d) Doing the same thing when it is slow?
e) Working on the same OS?
f) Experiencing slowdowns at the same time of day?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note about

> I assume they all have ample bandwidth comming into their office

I work for a corporation that has a ton of bandwidth. However, they force all their branches and offices to route traffic through one centralized firewall/proxy. As a result, the internet speed to some sites is very very bad - the same private channel between our office and IT office (that houses proxy) is used for 100s of other things that flow inside the corporation. And accessing internet is not a priority traffic - internal traffic (like file sharing and email) is the priority.

Comment: you should host a big file on your server and ask clients to download it and see how long it takes. The simplest version of speed detection :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) to profile your application. You can do that locally, on your development machines, to identify memory and CPU intensive operations.

If that doesn't expose any obvious issues (it probably will) you can also test your site within resource constrained virtual machines. It's quite easy to set up a VM with, for instance, 512MB RAM and see what happens.